# Navigation with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing, python-requests

I am slightly confused about how to use BeautifulSoup to navigate the HTML tree.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://examplewebsite.com'
source = requests.get(url)
content = source.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "html.parser")

# Now I navigate the soup
for a in soup.findAll('a'):
    print a.get("href")
```

1. Is there a way to find only *particular* `href` by the labels? For example, all the `href`'s I want are called by a certain name, e.g. `price` in an online catalog.
2. The `href` links I want are all in a certain location within the webpage, within the page's  and a certain . Can I access only *these* links?
3. How can I scrape the contents within each `href` link and save into a file format?

Comment: (2) What do you mean by "certain location". Can you give an excerpt of the source file? Is it "near a <h1>" tag or something? (3) What do you mean by the "contents" of the link? You want to download the file that is at the other end of the link?

Comment: @RobertB (2) Yes, I mean there are a number of `href` in a certain `<table>`
(3) You clink on a link until you reach a table of data. I would like to scrape that data.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With `BeautifulSoup`, that's all doable and simple.

> (1) Is there a way to find only particular href by the labels? For
>   example, all the href's I want are called by a certain name, e.g.
>   price in an online catalog.

Say, all the links you need have `price` in the text - you can use a `text` argument:

```
soup.find_all("a", text="price")  # text equals to 'price' exactly
soup.find_all("a", text=lambda text: text and "price" in text)  # 'price' is inside the text
```

Yes, you may use [functions](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) and many other different kind of objects to filter elements, like, for example, compiled [regular expressions](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression):

```
import re

soup.find_all("a", text=re.compile(r"^[pP]rice"))
```

If `price` is somewhere in the "href" attribute, you can have use the following [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("a[href*=price]")  # href contains 'price'
soup.select("a[href^=price]")  # href starts with 'price'
soup.select("a[href$=price]")  # href ends with 'price'
```

or, via `find_all()`:

```
soup.find_all("a", href=lambda href: href and "price" in href)
```

---

> (2) The href links I want are all in a certain location within the
>   webpage, within the page's and a certain . Can I access only these
>   links?

Sure, locate the appropriate container and call [`find_all()` or other searching methods](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree):

```
container = soup.find("div", class_="container")
for link in container.select("a[href*=price"):
    print(link["href"])
```

Or, you may write your CSS selector the way you search for links inside a specific element having the desired attribute or attribute values. For example, here we are searching for `a` elements having `href` attributes located inside a `div` element having `container` class:

```
soup.select("div.container a[href]")
```

---

> (3) How can I scrape the contents within each href link and save into
>   a file format?

If I understand correctly, you need to get appropriate links, follow them and save the source code of the pages locally into HTML files. There are multiple options to choose from depending on your requirements (for instance, speed may be critical. Or, it's just a one-time task and you don't care about performance).

If you would stay with `requests`, the code would be of a blocking nature - you'll extract the link, follow it, save the page source and then proceed to a next one - the main downside of it is that it would be slow (depending on, for starters, how much links are there). Sample code to get you going:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

base_url = 'http://examplewebsite.com'
with requests.Session() as session:  # maintaining a web-scraping session
    soup = BeautifulSoup(session.get(base_url).content, "html.parser")

    for link in soup.select("div.container a[href]"):
        full_link = urljoin(base_url, link["href"])
        title = a.get_text(strip=True)

        with open(title + ".html", "w") as f:
            f.write(session.get(full_link).content)
```

You may look into [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) or [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) to solve that part.

Comment: @alexce "follow them and save the source code of the pages locally into HTML files." Actually, I need to save the source code of each individual page into one HMTL file. So, think of this as a huge HTML tree over several webpages; I need to follow the links/children all the way down the tree, save this data, append to my file, and then continue.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang then it sounds like you need to open the same HTML file in the "append" mode, or just open once for writing and keep it open while following links and downloading pages. Thanks.